# Como faça para excluir apenas os registros de um campo da minha tabela no SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Bom dia, eu precisaria excluir apenas os registrados de um campo da minha tabela. No caso eu tenho a tabela produto e nela tem o campo dtsaneamento e nesse campo possuí registros. Eu precisaria excluir apenas os registros desse campo e manter a tabela e as outras informações intactas. Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma

```
UPDATE produto SET dtsaneamento = null;
```

**Editado**

Para apagar apenas os registros anteriores a data basta fazer assim

```
UPDATE produto SET dtsaneamento = null where campo_data < "2019-01-01";
```

Caso seu campo seja data e hora faça assim

```
UPDATE produto SET dtsaneamento = null where cast(campo_data as date) < "2019-01-01";
```

Comment: Uma coisa que eu esqueci de mencionar, eu preciso manter a data de 2019-01-01 em diante e as anteriores serão nulas, como ficaria o código ?

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro Verifique a edição da minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

```
update produto set dt_saneamento = null;
```

Dá um update na tabela setando o campo para null.

Answer (score 2):

tabela = Nome da sua tabela

coluna = Coluna que você quer limpar

```
UPDATE tabela SET coluna = NULL
```

No seu caso ficaria assim

```
UPDATE produto SET dtsaneamento = NULL
```

Comment: Uma coisa que eu esqueci de mencionar, eu preciso manter a data de 2019-01-01 em diante e as anteriores serão nulas, como ficaria o código ?

Comment: No caso adicione uma cláusula no seu UPDATE, ficaria dessa forma

UPDATE produto SET dtsaneamento = NULL WHERE data < 2019-01-01